# jQuery Cycle Plugin (zero element?)

Tags: jquery, cycle

I used AJAX to populate a div and then, [cycle plugin it](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager2.html) !

here is the [page](http://www.studioteknik.com/html2/photo-portfolio.php#), and here is the code calling cycle:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#photoviewer").load("photo-list.shtml #ani");
        alert ('photo loaded!');
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ani').cycle({ fx:      'turnDown',
                              speed:   'fast',
                              timeout: 0,
                              pager:   '#nav' });
            alert('done!');     
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get this error : [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector, but with firebug i SEE the image list as where it should be...

so i am clueless, any help welcome !

*** take note, the error console (warning section) is going crazy !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of initializing cycle in `$(document).ready()`, do it in a `load` callback so that it doesn't execute until your ajax call has completed and built the #ani `div`:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#photoviewer").load("photo-list.shtml #ani", function() {
            $('#ani').cycle({ fx:      'turnDown',
                              speed:   'fast',
                              timeout: 0,
                              pager:   '#nav' });
        });
    });
```

As it stands, the cycle plugin initialization is executing before the images have loaded (before the `load` function has finished).

Answer (score 3):

The error just means there is no selector named "#ani" available it seems like the "#ani" is a child node of "#photoviewer" and when the ajax request is complete it then adds "#ani".

After you call:

```
 $("#photoviewer").load("photo-list.shtml #ani");
```

Try this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
  if(jQuery("#ani").length > 0) {
    clearInterval(interval); 
    jQuery('#ani').cycle({fx:'turnDown', speed:  'fast', timeout: 0, pager:  '#nav'}); 
  }
}, 1);
```

Comment: one bad this about this is, you should be sure #ani is available otherwise the above code will always cycle.