# jquery cycle pager link not firing

Tags: jquery, cycle, pager

I have a jquery cycle with pager set up here: http://signature.codeventure.net/project/holland-cottage-2009/

The script to set it up appears to be running just fine.  It builds the pager from my list of images just fine.  The js I'm using is here: http://signature.codeventure.net/wp-content/themes/signature/js/signature.js  The bit related to this project is the third set.  The previous two are for more traditional sliders that are working fine elsewhere in the site.

Once my pager is built, the link don't change the activeSlide class on the main list of images like it's supposed to.

I've compared my code with the example code here: (link removed because I'm not allowed more than 2 links, but it's the example on the cycle page) without much luck.

I don't see any errors in Firebug.

Any ideas on how I can make the pager links change the active image?

Answer (score 0):

At the time your setup code executes in signature.js, there's nothing in `$('#project_thumbs')`, so the cycle doesn't have anything to iterate over.  I don't know how you're loading `#project_thumbs`, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657276/jquery-cycle-plugin-zero-element/1657728#1657728) suggests a possible solution to making sure that it's populated before you set up your cycle.

Comment: #project_thumbs is actually created by the cycle script, by iterating over the contents of #project_gallery.  I know that's working because the thumbs are being created.  What's not happening is the click action afterwards.

Comment: I made some small progress.  I have it now so that it cycles through them on its own, but click events still do nothing.