# Using remote JSON with jQuery

Tags: json, web-services, jquery, jsonp

I am using following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://servername/public_data.json",
  crossDomain:true,
  dataType:"jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
})
```

I want to use json coming from remote server but not getting the data. On executing the above code, following is what my console tells me:

```
jquery.cycle.all.latest.js:27[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
bidarea:242Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.
public_data.json:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

So where is the problem? and how can I solve it? Getting this response when I monitor this in chrome response:

```
{"price":22,"start_time":1323770479,"end_time":1323788469,"current_time":1323777486,"leader_list":   ["",""]}
```

But how can I use it? in which variable? not in data?

Comment: Maybe this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657276/jquery-cycle-plugin-zero-element

Comment: this seems very different, I think I am getting data as in chrome network monitor but how I can access it?

Comment: I have googled the "terminating; zero elements found by selector". If you get json back then you can just access the data as if it was multiple javascript arrays bundled together. The safest would be to check it first.