# IE Javascript not working but no errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, background

I'm trying to create a function that auto stretches the background to fill the window. The code works fine in all browsers except IE 8-, where nothing happens. Just, nothing!

This is the site i'm working on: http://goo.gl/BlqDS

Here's the javascript file (mostly jQuery): http://goo.gl/ITuUa

The relevant code is at the top, in the first `jQuery(document).ready()`.

I'm testing in IETester, which constantly crashes and behaves weird, so i'm not 100% sure it's not working, but i'm pretty sure it's not. I'm using debug toolbar with IETester and i get nothing from the console. I should at least get "no background found".

Any suggestions? Been looking at this for hours now!

Comment: I tried looking at this in all of the various IE9 compatibility modes, and it seemed to work correctly each time.

Comment: Yes, ie 9 seems to be working. There are only two compability modes for IE9, aren't there? And each one uses it's own rendering engine, one old and one new. I might be wrong though. Either way it has to work in IE 7+.

Comment: Correct, I tried in "Browser Mode" IE7 and IE8, as well as "Document Mode" IE7 and IE8 and any allowable combinations.  The image even shows up in Quirks Mode.  Maybe it's a bug that was corrected in IE9?

Comment: So, you're saying it works correctly in IE-7,8 and 9? Keep in mind that the background will always show up, but it's suppose to scale with the browser window, so when you resize the window it will fill the width (if it's wide enough).

Comment: I understand now; does the window `.resize` callback actually get triggered?

Comment: It does in non-IE browsers. But if you look at the top in the `if(jQuery('#custom-background-css').length) {...` statement, there are two `console.log()`'s in there. At least one of them should always fire, no matter what. That does not seem to be the case in IE, simply nothing happens. I don't even get one of those annoying pop-up errors wich i would usually not want to see, god damn it!

Comment: I went to that site using IE8.. and here's what I get in the console `LOG: "http://www.pfmresearch.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Nissan-50-proc_1680x1000.jpg"` and `LOG: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector`

Comment: Oh look at that! Then the debugbar plugin is not doing it's job. Well, does the background scale with the window? You don't possibly have IE7 available to test on as well, do you? The URL is what i was hoping for, that's good. The cycle thing i don't know about, it's not from my code (i'm guessing it's from a slideshow plugin).

Comment: If the second one isn't in your code.. you're going to have to find it and remove it or else the code isn't going to work in IE..  I don't have IE7 to test it in though.  And I don't see it scaling with the window. Unless I'm not understanding exactly what it's supposed to do.  Do you have an example?

Comment: Also.. heres a link to help you with the cycle thing http://stackoverflow.com/a/1657728/1385672

Comment: It's suppose to behave like it's behaving in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 or any other relatively new browser. The image should scale with the browser. Do you think the cycle thing breaks the script entirely, which causes my script to fail too? I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @explosion-pills has identified, IE is adding quotes around the URL in the CSS, you can therefore use a regular expression to get to the actual URL:

```
var burl = jQuery('body.custom-background').css('background-image');
burl = burl.match(/^url\((['"]*)(.*)(\1\))$/)[2];
```

Here the `\1` in the regular expression refers to the first captured sub-pattern which is the quote (whether it is single, double or not there).

Comment: I tried removing the quotes with the replace function as well, but it didn't work! Tried both single and double quotes. I also tried a bunch of different regex patterns, none of which worked. Yours, however, works flawlessly! I've spent wayyy too much time working on this, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the img `src` is not being set correctly (you may notice a broken image in the top left in IE8-).  I figured this out by looking in IE's developer tools as well .. the `src` is empty and it tries to set an attribute that is part of the name of the image url.  I'm not 100% sure why, but you could give this a shot:

```
- jQuery('body').append('<img id="body-background-img" src="'+ burl +'" />')
+ jQuery('body')
+    .append(jQuery("<img>", {'id': 'body-background-img', 'src': burl}));
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect; look carefully.  You have `.append('<img>'...` whereas I have `.append(jQuery('<img>'...`.  There is a vital difference!

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Code is correct now, works in Chrome as expected but not in IE.

Comment: @qwerty Okay, after more experimentation it seems like for whatever stupid reason, IE changes the `url('...` to `url("...`, so your `.replace` is not working properly.  The quotes are not necessary when using `url()`, so maybe you can remove them?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't, it's built into Wordpress and stuff. Wish i had more control, but that's Wordpress in a nutshell. So the problem is the `.replace()` function right? Can't i just change that to remove the quotes as well? Like `burl.replace("url('",'').replace("')",'');`

Comment: Sure you can, or use a regular expression

Comment: Regular expression seem to be the better option here, right? I tried a few different variants before, but none of them worked as i wanted. You don't happen to be a regular expression ninja, do you?

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, am i doing it correctly? `burl = burl.replace(/url\(('|")(.*?)\1\)/, '$2');`

Comment: @qwerty you mean `burl` is empty?  Can you show me in jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to try instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {...});
```

Just try using

```
$(function () {...});
```

Comment: I can't, jQuery is in compability mode. It's the default by Wordpress (sigh!).

Comment: You mean you can't use $ as jQuery function? Then just jQuery(function() {...}) should work anyway

Comment: So you're saying if i do something like: `jQuery(function() {  code using $   });` it will work?

Comment: And either way, i strongly doubt that is the issue since it's working fine in all browsers except for IE.

Comment: I want to say maybe it's a problem how you fire your startup script. The $ and jQuery functions are the same, only $ is shorter to write.

Comment: Yes, i see what you're saying. :) But since, as you just said yourself, `jQuery` and `$` is the exact same, it shouldn't matter what i use, right?

Comment: Only in case you have some other library that overrides $ variable, then there may be compatibility issues. But yes, it should be the same thing