# cycle terminating; zero elements found by selector

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jQuery slider and I keep getting an 'error loading image' message, although the slider loads perfectly fine after I click 'okay'.

I believe the answer to problem is here: [jQuery Cycle Plugin (zero element?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657276/jquery-cycle-plugin-zero-element) but as this is all very new to me I don't really understand what it all means, or indeed, how I can make use of it.

This is the script that I have identified as being the cause of the problem:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".container").wtListRotator({
        screen_width: 600,
        screen_height: 300,
        item_width: 250,
        item_height: 75,
        item_display: 4,
        list_align: "left",
        scroll_type: "none",
        auto_start: true,
        delay: 5000,
        transition: "v.slide",
        transition_speed: 800,
        easing: "",
        auto_center: true,
        display_playbutton: true,
        display_number: false,
        display_timer: false,
        display_arrow: true,
        display_thumbs: true,
        display_scrollbar: true,
        mouseover_select: false,
        pause_mouseover: false,
        cpanel_mouseover: false,
        text_mouseover: false,
        text_effect: "fade",
        text_sync: true,
        cpanel_align: "TR",
        timer_align: "bottom",
        move_one: false,
        auto_adjust: true,
        shuffle: true,
        play_once: false,
        mousewheel_scroll: true,
        touch_swipe: false,
        block_size: 75,
        vert_size: 50,
        horz_size: 50,
        block_delay: 35,
        vstripe_delay: 90,
        hstripe_delay: 180
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
<div class="container" width:900px;>
    <div class="l-rotator">
        <div class="screen">

        </div>
        <div class="thumbnails" style="left:30px;">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/GME-icon1.png" alt=""/>
                        <p><span class="title">GM Electrical</span><br/>NIC EIC Registered Electrician.</p>
                  </div>
                <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/GME-slider-image.png"></a>
                    <a href="/listing/gm-electrical/" target="_blank"></a>                        
                    <div style="top:10px; left:20px; width:550px; height:70px;">
                        <h1>GM Electrical</h1>
                       NIC EIC registered Electrician with over 30 years experience providing high quality, competitively priced services.
                    </div>                                       
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/become-listed-icon.png" alt=""/>
                        <p><span class="title">Front Page Listing!</span><br/>Get listed on the front page!</p>
                  </div>
                <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Become-listed-2.png"></a>

                                       <div class = "become-listed-button" style="background-color: transparent;">
                    <a href="/add-listing/#my1" style=" display: block; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); font-family: advent; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bolder; text-align: center; padding: 12px 8px; text-decoration: none;">Click here to find out more!</a>
                    </div>                    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Berkshire-Sparks-icon.png" alt=""/>
                        <p><span class="title">Berkshire Sparks</span><br/>Qualified Electrician In Reading|24h Emergency Call Out|</p>
                  </div>
                <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Berkshire-Sparks-slider-image.png"></a>
                    <a href="/listing/qualified-electrician-in-reading-berkshire-sparks-24h-emergency-call-out/" target="_blank"></a>
                    <div style="top:10px; left:20px; width:350px; height:0;">
                        <h1>Berkshire Sparks</h1>
                        Qualified Electrician In Reading | Berkshire Sparks | 24h Emergency Call Out |
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/My-Graphic-icon.png" alt=""/>
                        <p><span class="title">My Graphic</span><br/>Custom Printing Solutions.</p>
                  </div>
                <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/My-Graphic-slider-image.png"></a>
                    <a href="/listing/t-shirt-printing-mugs-hats-custom-cake-prints-apple-devices-all-garments/" target="_blank"></a>
                    <div style="top:10px; left:260px; width:325px; height:0;">
                        <h1>My Graphic</h1>
                       T Shirt Printing | Mugs | Hats | Custom Cake Prints | Apple Devices | All Garments |
                    </div>                  
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html as well

Comment: Is this what you need? I had to post it above.

Comment: Still dont see html, your jquery selector is defined in jQuery(".container"), are you sure you have .container elements in html? I dont know the wtListRotator function, but if it calls the cycle plugin, you might want to make sure that the selector gets passed right, I would do some console.log-debugging in the wtListRotator function definition...

Comment: ok, looks all good so far...if you dont mind, please post a link to your site

Comment: http://readingindex.com/

I've just changed the '.container' in the script and the html to '.slider3' and that seems to have worked. Although I still don't understand why.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense that it works now...the class "container" is used in your menu already...so wtListRotator() got wrong html passed as well...always make sure your selectors are distinct, which you did by naming it slider3 ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. I'm glad it's no longer a problem. Cheers :)