# jQuery Cycle Plugin [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do a cycle of background images on hover of a centralised logo, and have used [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).

However, I get this error : [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector,

I've looked at the other [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657276/jquery-cycle-plugin-zero-element) that seems to have the same problem as me, but it doesn't seem to resolve the error I have.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. Please see code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="home" href="#">
    <a href="#about">
        <img id="logo" src="images/home/parableLogo.png"/>
    </a>

    <ul class="imgfill"> 
        <li><img src="images/home/1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/home/2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/home/3.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/home/4.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/home/5.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Cycle plugin
        $('.imgfill').cycle({
            fx:     'none',
            speed:   1,
            timeout: 70
        }).cycle("pause");

        // Pause & play on hover
        $('#logo').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.imgfill').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.imgfill').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
        });

    });
```

test JQUERY following other user's solutions:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Cycle plugin
        $('.home').load('.imgfill', function(){
            $('.imgfill').cycle({
            fx:     'none',
            speed:   1,
            timeout: 70
            }).cycle("pause");
        });


        // Pause & play on hover
        $('#logo').hover(function(){
            $('.home').find('.imgfill').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
        }, function(){
            $('.home').find('.imgfill').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Did you try implementing what the answer on the other question suggested?

Comment: try to replace $(this) with $('.home') instead. In this context $(this) is a #logo element. Inside #logo there no .imgfill selector

Comment: @AlmasK89 hi, thanks for that. the error is gone, but the cycle is not working, any idea why?

Comment: @AndrewL I've tried, but might have done it incorrectly hence the cycle is not occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using a wrong selector "$(this).find('.imgfill')" you shoud use "$('.imgfill')"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Cycle plugin
    $('.imgfill').cycle({
        fx:     'none',
        speed:   1,
        timeout: 70
    }).cycle("pause");

    // Pause & play on hover
    $('#logo').hover(function(){
        $('.imgfill').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
    }, function(){
        $('.imgfill').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
    });

});
```

here is a link for a working version 
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/eZqLxr

Comment: thank you. also realise I had .imgfill on hidden, hence it wasn't showing. the following: $('.home').find('.imgfill') works as well, but is probably an additional step to use .find